# How to remove the "Forgot Password" link from the signIn page in Azure B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How can we remove the "Forgot password" link from the signIn page is Azure AD B2C login.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you not hide it with JS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

Answer (score 6):

In the metadata section of your technical profile add:

```xml
<Metadata>
 <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">none</Item>
 </Metadata>
```

Options:

```
AfterLabel (Default)
AfterInput
AfterButtons
none
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own HTML and CSS in your user experience pages and host this HTML content in Blob storage.

Then read the HTML from Blob storage in TrustFrameworkBase.xml.

What you need to do is modify the [resetpassword.html](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-AzureBlobStorage-Client/blob/master/sample_templates/wingtip/resetpassword.html).

See details from [Customize the user interface of your application using a custom policy in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom).